# mod_expires does not affect caching

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, cache, apache-2.2

I have mod_expires installed in Apache on CentOS VPS. It is also listed in the loaded modules, I checked by this command `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -l`

When I place the code in .htaccess, and then analyze my website with [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) or [Gmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/), they both indicate 1 hour expire for css,jpg,png files, ignoring the .htaccess code that sets 1 year for jpg,png files and 1 month for the css.

I removed the `<ifmodule>` from .htaccess also to double check that mod_expires is working and my site didn't respond with 500 internal server error. So it should be working!

**Here is my .htaccess:**

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
```

Am I missing something? Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Add something random to your .htaccess so you know it is being parsed.

Comment: For performance reasons .htaccess processing is often defaulted to off for most directories. The advice to check it's being parsed/used is good advice. Check if AllowOveride is All and not None.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem, as I am running into similar issues. Everything seems to be set up properly but not being reported as working when I run the website through Google Pagespeed. I am also running Centos 6.6 but have never had this trouble before with Ubuntu VPS's.

Answer (score 0):

mod_expires doesn't override Expires headers if they're already present from whatever originally generated them (dynamic app, proxy, etc)